Different versions of global Angular CLI and project version
I have angular CLI 17.0.0 installed globally on my machine and I am creating projects from it, but the projects created when I run the ng version command in their directory, the project's angular CLI version comes as 17.3.11, in package.json file the version is 17.0.0 equal to the global version installed on the machine
What could be happening?

In the project.json file, is the angular-cli version set to "^17.0.0"? The caret (^) is significant.

yes, that, why? @MrZane2u

Yes, the caret is a range specifier. In this case, ^17.0.0 basically means >=17.0.0 && <18.0.0. If you change the entry to 17.0.0 and run npm i again, it should install the version you want.
